# Are Git Commits Saved/Persistant?

Tags: git, persistence, git-commit

Are Git Commits Saved/Persistant? So, if my computer reboots my commits are still there ready to be pushed to a remote repository? Or do I have to push every time I want to turn off my computer?

I am working on WIndows 10, but I would like to know if the answer also applies to Linux.

**Edit**:

If I reboot my computer. would I have to re-stage and commit before pushing to a remote repository?

Comment: Remote repository is just an addition to git. Everything you commit is stored in the .git folder on the disk.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Yes, but what about the commits them selves? If I reboot my computer. would I have to re-stage and commit before pushing to a remote repository?

Comment: Git is a distributed protocol and all repositories are fully autonomous.

Comment: Everything inside a Git repository is stored in files inside the `.git` sub-directory of your project. Git doesn't keep anything in memory between two invocations. Every time you run a Git command it reads the information from files and, if appropriate, stores new information in them. Having this information, please figure out yourself the answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any git commit will be on your disk and hence persistent. You do not need to re-stage or re-commit just because you haven't pushed.

I actually do this all the time where I commit locally because I want to essentially save my state but I don't push my change to our server if my code is in a temporary state and I know it won't pass the CI.